# Как сделать схему и контракт БД в Андроид приложении при вложенных таблицах?

Tags: android, база-данных, join

Во всех примерах, что я нашёл, в том числе [официальном](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html), используется одна простая таблица. Здесь да, всё просто. В обычной JavaEE это выглядело понятно и логично, с использованием аннотаций JPA. Например, в нашем случае, на объекте Report у меня было бы поле:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinTable(name="test_procedure_table")
private Set<Step> testSequence;
```

А как здесь это сделать я понятия не имею. Тем более, что не рекомендуется работать напрямую с запросами SQLite, нужно делать это через контент провайдера. Мне хотя бы раз объяснить и показать, я бы понял.

Comment: контент-провайдер для выборки данных используется только если доступ к БД необходимо предоставить другим приложениям на устройстве (как например Контакты на устройстве)

Comment: Все пишется на чистом SQL, запросы тоже на чистом SQL, все олдскульно, никаких аннотаций и тому подобного - только хардкор. Запросы делать нужно через метод query() (rawQuery()) класса SQLiteDatabase, а не через контент-провайдер.

Comment: @pavlofff, это не проблема. Но как быть с контрактом и хелпером? Что там указывать в полях DataContract - int id строки другой таблицы или сразу список объектов?

Comment: Уточните ваш вопрос. Что именно вы хотите получить, какие таблицы как должны быть связаны, что от них нужно получить в итоге, конкретный пример решаемой задачи, в текущем виде из вашего вопроса трудно понять, в чем именно у вас проблема.

Comment: @pavlofff, допустим, есть таблица испытаний. В ней есть дата/время, название и объект испытания. Для нормализации есть таблица объектов, а там размер вес, тип, производитель. Соответственно, нужны ещё таблицы "типы объектов" и "производители". Я хочу понять, как со всем этим работать в андроиде.

Comment: Напишите ваше дополнение в вопрос (кнопка "править" под вопросом), а не в комментарии. Если вы хотите работать с БД SQLite, то все решается классической связью SQL один ко многим (многие ко многим) которые достаточно подробно изложены в любой литературе по реляционным СУБД. Кратко: таблицам "производители", "объекты", "типы объектов" присваиваете ID каждой записи, в результирующей таблице испытаний ссылаетесь на эти записи по соответствующим им ID.

Comment: Для выборки используете SQL запрос вида:`SELECT object.id, test.rec, test.id FROM object, test  WHERE object.[id]=test.id_object` - получите курсор с выборкой из таблицы `test` по колонке `rec` (и служебные колонки с ID) для которых указан object с ID = id. Связь многие ко многим организуется через дополнительную служебную таблицу кросс-связей. Если вы приведете структуры таблиц и какие именно выборки требуется получить, я смогу написать примеры таких выборок.

Comment: Как делать запросы я знаю, это легко, тем более в лайте. В Java EE это делается элементарно. Меня интересует схема и контракт, контент провайдер - как вот это делается на манер андроида.

Answer (score 0):

Я рекомендую вам посмотреть в сторону ORM (http://greenrobot.org/greendao/).

Тогда то, что вам нужно, впринципе делается аналогично как и в JavaEE.

```
@Entity
public class Report {
    @Id private Long id;

    @ToMany(referencedJoinProperty = "reportId")
    private List<Step> testSequence;
}

@Entity
public class Step {
    @Id private Long id;
    private String somedata;
    private long reportId;
}
```

Более подробную информацию можн почитать [здесь](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/relations/).

Comment: На курсах Advanced Android нам настоятельно советовали избегать всяческих ORM и вообще, runtime фрэймворков. Тем более у нас на проекте устройство с 1 ядром 600Mhz и 256 оперативки. Но если я не пойму, как работать стандартными средствами, то, наверное, буду вынужден использовать ORM.

Comment: @Eugene а что за крсы такие интересные, если не секрет? это не совсем runtime... все объекты и структуры создаются в процессе сборки и потом уже компилятся... Соответственно нет никакой непредсказуемости, как по производительности так и по поведению